# Getting blank white page in Drupal admin/content

Tags: php, mysql, drupal

I've seen this issue happen before with pages outside of the admin.. but never had this issue happen inside of the admin. I just get a blank white page with no errors when I go to www.example.com/admin/content. I checked the php, mysql, and apache error logs and there are no errors being written when I browse to the content page. Any ideas what the issue could be? :-/

**Update..**
Alright.. I figured it out. There was a page that had some images with some screwed up src attributes. The src was full of thousands of lines of random characters. No idea how or why that happened. I removed those lines from the database and all is good.

Comment: Have you looked at http://drupal.org/node/158043?

Comment: Yep I've looked at that. I still don't get any errors when I have error reporting turned on :( The memory limit on the server is also set to 128M. Nothing changed within the templates. The client alerted us of the issue when they were putting content into the site.

Comment: Would you mind telling me how you deleted the page from the database? I am having the exact same problem and it happened right after someone was trying to put a photo on the page with ckeditor...

Answer (score 0):

I know this post is old, but, I had a similar problem and was able to find the "node" area in the database.

For me, I went into the cpanel of my site, then the phpadmin, then found my database name, from there, a directory with a prefix_node was listed, clicked on that and went to the last page to find the most recent posts/pages. From there I was able to delete the problem pages (which are nodes in drupal)